# Is it possible to migrate from asp.net cookie auth (using machineKey) to asp.net core without having to re-login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got an app I'm trying to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC 5 running on .NET Framework 4.7.2 to ASP.NET Core 2.2 (running on Windows at the moment).

I know there are docs that explain how to set up cookie sharing between asp.net and asp.net core projects, but from all the docs I've seen, they all involve changing the dataprotection provider in the asp.net project, which would necessarily render the auth cookies unusable if I'm not mistaken.

1. Is there any way to make asp.net core cookie auth be 100% compatible asp.net's cookie auth?  Or 2. Perhaps better, is there a way to migrate the existing asp.net auth cookie to the new format in asp.net core, all without logging out the user?

I should mention as well that both these projects are using identity and sharing the underlying tables.  That part I've got working just fine.

Comment: Simply. No. They're completely incompatible. The methodology to share cookies between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core is enabled simply by OWIN support that was added to ASP.NET, which creates a sort of common ground both can work from. If you weren't already using that, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I suspected, but just wanted to make sure.